# Determine if the two graphs are isomorphic

Tags: graph-isomorphism

Let G be the graph with vertex and edge sets
$$V = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$$ and $$E = \{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\}\}$$

and H be the graph with vertex and edge sets

$$V = \{a, b, c, d\} $$and
$$E = \{\{a,b\},\{a,d\},\{b,c\},\{a,c\},\{c,d\}\}$$
Question is "write down an isomorphism between them?"
i have chosen the following

$$ϕ(1)=a$$
$$ϕ(2)=c$$
$$ϕ(3)=b$$
$$ϕ(4)=d$$
Number of edges $$|E_1|=|E_2|=5$$
Degree sequence for $$|V_1|=3,3,2,2$$
$$|V_2|=3,2,3,2$$

$$ϕ(\{1,2\})=\{a,c\},ϕ(\{1,3\})=\{a,b\},ϕ(\{1,4\})=\{a,d\},ϕ(\{2,3\})=\{c,b\},$$

$$ϕ(\{2,4\})=\{c,d\}$$
therefore they are isomorphic
is my method correct is there a better way to show it?

Also how do you figure the number of isomorphism two graphs have between them

Any type of help will be much appreciated

Comment: Try to avoid abuse of notation like $$|V_1|=3,3,2,2$$ Forst, $|V_1|=4.$ And this sequence isn’t a property of $V_1,$ it  is a property of $G_1=(V_1,E_1).$ Instead, write the two line like: $$(V_1,E_1): 3,3,2,2$$ or $$G_1: 3,3,2,2$$

Comment: Re: "*It's not sufficient to use degree sequence to show they are isomorphic*"  Compare the two graphs... the first of which consisting of a triangle and a pentagon (*a disjoint $C_3$ and a $C_5$*) versus the second graph consisting of two squares (*two disjoint copies of $C_4$*).  Both of these graphs have the same number of vertices, same number of edges, same degree sequence $2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2$ and a number of other properties and yet are not isomorphic.  The first is not bipartite for instance while the second is.

Comment: are the two graphs not isomorphic ?

Answer (score 3):

Comparing properties can show that two graphs are *not* isomorphic.  but cannot reliably be used to show graphs are isomorphic.  Consider these two:

[[image: drawing of the graph <span class=]$(\{a,b,c,d,e,f\},\{\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{c,d\},\{d,e\},\{d,f\}\})$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQCxw.png)

[[image: drawing of the graph <span class=]$(\{1,2,3,4,5,6\},\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{3,4\},\{4,5\},\{3,6\}\})$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsyLW.png)

These two graphs have the same number of vertices (6) and edges (5), and the same degree sequences ($3,2,2,1,1,1$), but are not isomorphic.  The first graph's degree 3 vertex has two neighbors with degree 1, but the second graph's degree 3 vertex has two neighbors with degree 2.

To show that graphs are isomorphic, you most often need to exhibit an isomorphism.  You gave a function $G$ from $V_1$ to $V_2$.  You need to show:

- $G$ is a bijection from $V_1$ to $V_2$, and
- for all $x$ and $y$ in $V_1$, $(x \sim y) \iff G(x) \sim G(y)$.

There are many ways to show a function is a bijection.  Since $G$ is a function from one finite set to another of the same size, it's sufficient to show that $G$ is injective.

Since $|V_1| = 4$, there are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ sets of distinct vertices $x$ and $y$.  You can just write down all of them and check if adjacent vertices in the first graph are sent by $G$ to adjacent vertices in the second graph.

Comment: how do i show that there is a bijection and how did you figure that there are six cases?

Comment: see edits; hope that answers your questions

Comment: is that the way to find out the number of isomophism

Comment: There are $4! = 24$ bijections from $V_1$ to $V_2$, but most of them will not be graph isomorphisms.  You may want to review the important properties of graph isomorphisms.  For instance, if $v$ is a vertex and $f$ is an isomorphism, then the degree of $f(v)$ is the same as the degree of $v$.  That can help you narrow it down.

Comment: i am still confused on how to show that the two graphs are isomorphic I thought my attempt was sufficient (well sort of) by showing the number of vertices,edges and degree sequence

Comment: does showing {u, v} ∈ E1 if and only if {ϕ(u), ϕ(v)} ∈ E2 show its isomorphism (updated version)?

Comment: yes, but you have only shown the forward direction of “if and only if”.  Since $\{3,4\}\notin E_1$, you need to also verify that $\{\phi(3),\phi(4)\}\notin E_2$.

Comment: how would i do that as its a non edge

Comment: $E_2$ is a finite set.  Is $\{b,d\} \in E_2$ or not?

Comment: no, so showing the "positive direction" in this case is enough to show that the two graphs are isomorphic,right ?

Comment: Basically, yes, but as a grader I would look for some reference to the "negative direction" (trivial as it may be)